# Why has !== lower precedence than === in Scala?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

Following code does not compile:

```
implicit class TripleEq(val x: Int) {
  def === (y: Int) = x == y
  def !== (y: Int) = x != y
}

val a = 0
val b = 1

if (a == a && b === b) {
  println("Equal")
}

if (a != b && a !== b) {
  println("Not equal")
}
```

The error is:

> type mismatch;
>    found   : Int
>    required: Boolean

The error goes away when I enclose the `a !== b` in parentheses.

I thought that operator precedence is defined by its first letter (see [Tour of Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html)) and therefore the precedence of `!==` should be the same as of `===`, `!=` or `==`.

Why are parentheses required in the code above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the language specification of [Assignment Operators](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators):

> There's one exception to this rule, which concerns *assignment operators*. The precedence of an assignment operator is the same as the one of simple assignment (=). That is, it is lower than the precedence of any other operator.
>
> **6.12.14 Assignment Operators**
>
> An *assignment operator* is an operator symbol (syntax category op in Identifiers) that ends in an equals character “=”, with the exception of operators for which one of the following conditions holds:
>
> - the operator also starts with an equals character, or
> - the operator is one of (<=), (>=), (!=).

Based on these rules `!==` is considered to be an assignment operator, while `===` is not.

Comment: that sounds like an unfortunate, though mild, limitation in the language

Comment: I think it would match more with the intuition of the programmer if the exception condition where changed to: "the operator is recognized by the regular expression `[<>!=]=+`.

Comment: Note that the standard workaround is to put the relational operator in the middle, e.g. `=!=` (used by Spark, I believe).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think, it would actually match the intuition a lot better, if the whole paragraph was replaced with "assignment operator is the one that matches regex `^[^<>!=]?=$`" :)